# Why does user authentication via OpenLDAP work everywhere except for MacOS 11 login and Time Machine?

Tags: macos, time-machine, smb, authentication, ldap

I have an OpenLDAP directory on an Ubuntu server that I am trying to use for user management, authentication and various other goodies. I can use this directory and its authentication information to:

- log in to Ubuntu machines
- mount NFS volumes from Synology on Ubuntu machines
- mount NFS volumes from Synology on MacOS 11 machines
- authenticate iOS and iPadOS devices with Radius
- authenticate on MacOS in Directory Utility' Directory Editor
- ...

So I have done something right. However, the following  are things that I cannot do, and I would be grateful for any wise words or advice that would help me:

- on MacOS use an SMB/APFS disk exported from another Mac as a Time Machine backup disk
- log in to a MacOS machine

**(Edited below after a weekend of trial and error.)**

When I try to select the SMB disk from another Mac to use for TM backup, I select the disk, put in the user's name and password, and hit "Connect". After a couple of seconds the window wobbles to indicate that the authentication has failed. In my logs I see the following

```
default 02:03:58.332679+0200    digest-service  digest-request: uid=0
default 02:03:58.332710+0200    digest-service  digest-request: init request
default 02:03:58.340797+0200    digest-service  digest-request: have no nodes with signing
default 02:03:58.342099+0200    digest-service  digest-request: init return domain: S-MAC-CW server: S-FMAC-CW indomain was: <NULL>
default 02:03:59.323723+0200    digest-service  digest-request: uid=0
default 02:03:59.334501+0200    digest-service  digest-request: authentication failed
default 02:03:59.334522+0200    digest-service  digest-request: od failed with -1561745586 proto=ntlmv2
default 02:03:59.334815+0200    digest-service  digest-request: user=S-MAC-CW\steve
default 02:03:59.335592+0200    digest-service  digest-request: kdc failed with 36150275 proto=unknown
default 02:03:59.335618+0200    digest-service  digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv2
```

"steve" is the login name and the associated data is stored in the LDAP directory. "s-mac-cw" is the name of the machine I'm trying to log in to.
The crux of the matter seems to me to be that he Mac is trying to authenticate the user S-MAC-CW\steve. *There is no such user.* S-MAC-CW is the MacMini, the domain is HOME so the Mac should be trying to authenticate HOME\steve.

Noting the reference to NTLMv2, I have ensured that NTLM is one of the `supportedSASLMechanisms` recognised by OpenLDAP. I have also switched off SMB signing on the server and on the client.

The LDAP logs simply show a successful lookup of the user "steve":

```
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=2 SRCH base="dc=home,dc=arpa" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=shadowAccount))(|(uid=steve)(cn=steve)))"
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=2 SRCH attr=uid
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=2 ENTRY dn="uid=steve,cn=users,dc=family,dc=home,dc=arpa"
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=3 SRCH base="dc=home,dc=arpa" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=shadowAccount))(|(uid=steve)(cn=steve)))"
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=3 SRCH attr=uidNumber uid userPassword
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=3 ENTRY dn="uid=steve,cn=users,dc=family,dc=home,dc=arpa"
May  3 02:37:08 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=4 SRCH base="dc=home,dc=arpa" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=shadowAccount))(|(uid=steve)(cn=steve)))"
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=4 SRCH attr=uid
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=4 ENTRY dn="uid=steve,cn=users,dc=family,dc=home,dc=arpa"
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=5 SRCH base="dc=home,dc=arpa" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=shadowAccount))(|(uid=steve)(cn=steve)))"
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=5 SRCH attr=uidNumber uid userPassword
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=5 ENTRY dn="uid=steve,cn=users,dc=family,dc=home,dc=arpa"
May  3 02:37:10 s-hrt0-cw slapd[311178]: conn=1208 op=5 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
```

Note there is no mention of `sambaNTPassword`, which I would have expected if SMB was invoking NTLM.

After this sequence the user name/password window does its wobble.

I am flummoxed and would appreciate some help in interpreting these error messages and solving the underlying problem.

Steve

Comment: I had a hard time getting 10.15 machines bound to openldap. For logging in/ACL/Group membership checks, I had to add the apple schemas and backfill GUID info to each user/group. But it'll never fully work as the SASL mechanisms required by some services aren't supported by openldap out of the box. Here's my question about [authentication against openldap for smb sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416432/authenticate-smb-file-sharing-on-macos-10-15-bound-to-openldap/419722#419722)

Comment: @doggie_breath Thanks for reminding me that I’m dealing with SMB here. I have been working with the Apple UI (Sharing, Directory Utility), which obscures that significant issue. I’ve thrown SMB out everywhere else, but it seems to be effectively required for TM. How long before Apple starts pushing Windows, I wonder 

Comment: I think I can see what is happening. After @doggie_breath's reminder that I'm dealing with Samba, I discovered that SSH is also not working with LDAP. It seems to me that Apple has used its UI to simplify access to _some_ underlying technologies, but not _all_. The question now is how far can I get by treating my Macs as simple Unix machines (e.g. modifying `/etc/pam.d`) before the whole thing comes tumbling down around my ears. Watch this space...